# Flutter NetworkImage throwing Error after 533 response from picsum

Tags: image, dart, flutter

In my flutter app, I have a container with a Decoration Image. That decoration Image is a NetworkImage:

```
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    image: DecorationImage(
      image: NetworkImage(
        widget.data["backdrop"]
      ) ?? null,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      fit:BoxFit.cover
    )
  ),
)
```

where: `widget.data["backdrop"] = https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random`

But sometimes, when I run this, it throws an Exception. Unfortunately I dont have the error, cuz it happens at random. But here's the exception being thrown (from Flutter's `image_provider.dart` file):

```
 final HttpClientResponse response = await request.close();
if (response.statusCode != HttpStatus.ok)
  throw Exception('HTTP request failed, statusCode: ${response?.statusCode}, $resolved');
```

Please how do I fix it, or detect the error.

Comment: If you get the exception in debug builds you should be able to copy it from the IDE console. There is hardly a way to help without knowing what the exception is. 533 means it's an error on the server side anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Image.Network(widget.data["backdrop"]);
```

This will directly pull the image from the network and show it in the Image widget.

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged on StackOverflow, perhaps  you could include why OP made a mistake and what this does to fix it. Thanks!